# Update row base on distinct, stuff, path query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Continue from [Combine multiple rows into one "memo" nvarchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087645/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-memo-nvarcharmax)

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT fileref, stuff(
        (
        Select char(13)+char(10) + IsNull( D2.viaccno, '' )
        From vi_accno As D2
        Where D2.vifileref = A.FileRef
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') As accno
FROM
   vtindex a
```

How do i use the above query to update each accno row on table 1 matching fileref = fileref

table 1:
id, fileref, client, addr, accno

Comment: Please provide samples of data, DDL for creating tables, expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on given data, I can offer you this:

```
UPDATE t
SET accno = p.accno 
FROM [table 1] t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    DISTINCT fileref, stuff(
        (
        Select char(13)+char(10) + IsNull( D2.viaccno, '' )
        From vi_accno As D2
        Where D2.vifileref = A.FileRef
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') As accno
FROM
   vtindex a
) as p
ON p.fileref= t.fileref
```

Comment: query executed good  but results spanned the same accno to each row on  table t

Comment: Then provide samples of data that produce your query, and sample of data from `table_1`.

Comment: never mind i put in the wrong table [table 1] change that to vtindex, now they query was 10x faster and updated vtindex from  the distinct query, thanks for the help